# NetLogo 6.2.2 BehaviorSpace not letting us select file to save results or run

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

A student in my class is unable to get BehaviorSpace to work on his machine. We are able to design and save experiment. When we click on run the dialog box for Run options opens and we select Table output. Then the problem arises. After clicking Ok it goes right back to the BehaviorSpace dialog, rather than asking us where to save the results and running the experiment. If we click on Run again, we go back to Run options and so on. I have never seen this before. If you have any ideas, please let us know.

He is using a 2020 MacBook Air running macOS Monterey 12.0.1.

Sincerely, Dale S. Rothman